# Pros and cons of python and R for machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning

Some people use python for machine learning, other people use R. What are the pros and cons of using Python compare to R for ML?

Answer (score -2):

Python is a *much* easier-to-understand language than R, and has exponentially more support from the community online. It also has powerful and well-supported ML/data libraries, including [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/), [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) and [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

Pretty much any paradigm you're looking for in R — dataframes, graphic plotting, etc. — are available in Python. And you won't spend nearly as much time picking through arcane script with an un-Googleable name.